# How many permutations of [9] have no adjacent odd digits?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> How many permutations of [9] have no adjacent odd digits?

For example, a permutation like 385164927 is not allowed because 5 and 1 are adjacent.

Wouldn't the answer just be 4!5!? Since each even number must be placed between 2 odd numbers, we have 4! ways to arrange the even numbers. Then we have 5 spaces in between the odd numbers to arrange: so that would be 5!. Right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: If $[n] = \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ then yes, your solution is correct.  I think I've seen some define $[n] = \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, and in that case, the answer is slightly more involved.

Comment: Please choose more specific titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been stated in the comments, your approach and result are correct.

Comment: @Leucippus: It does provide an answer to the question. The question was "Right?". The answer is "Right." It had been provided in the comments, and no one had anything to add for $5$ hours, since there isn't much to add. From experience, the question will remain unanswered and contribute to clogging the system unless someone posts the (albeit trivial) answer from the comments as an answer. I did so with a community wiki post so as not to claim undue credit. Please remove your delete vote so the question can be marked as answered.